# Deleting an item in ListView from a file C#

Tags: c#, listview

How can I delete an item from a ListView, and also delete it from a file?
Here is the code I currently have:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
                File.Delete(path + "//Lyrics//" + item.Text + ".txt");                  
    }
```

This deletes item from a list, but does not delete its file. It only deletes the file when I select multiple items. For example, I selected 3 items: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt. It will only delete the file from the last one I selected, which is 3.txt, but will remove all 3 from the list.

Comment: First delete it from disc, and then from the list, since the selecteditem might become null because you deleted it!

Comment: Thank you so much!! Such a simple solution.. At least I won't make these silly mistakes anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *materialize* the items to be deleted into a list and then delete:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var toDelete = listView1.SelectedItems.ToList();

  foreach(var item in toDelete) {
    listView1.Items.Remove(item);
    File.Delete(path + "//Lyrics//" + item.Text + ".txt");
  } 
}
```